# Does Anyone know of a good Mask-Renaming Class I could add to my VB.Net App?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I don't think this would be too hard to write myself, but I'm hoping I won't have to re-create the wheel here and someone already has done this / can point me in the right direction...

Basically, I'm looking for a class (preferably in VB.Net so I could attach it to my existing apps & customize it if necessary) that allows the user to format what the program's output file names will look like. 
So, for example, suppose my program was creating information about dogs and creating output files. Maybe I would offer the user masks such as:

```
<Breed>
<Sex>
<Age>
etc
```

Then the user could use this utility to create an output file name such as:

```
"Dog Info - "<Sex>" "<Breed><Index>".txt"
```

And The program would output the files:

```
"Dog Info - Male Doberman.txt"
"Dog Info - Female Maltese.txt"
"Dog Info - Female Rottweiler1.txt"
"Dog Info - Female Rottweiler2.txt"
```

... Something along these lines...

Again, I'm pretty sure this wouldn't be a big deal to program, but it would be REALLY cool if it already existed and maybe someone did a better job than I would thinking through potential issues.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try String.Replace? Should work well, because file names cannot contain angle brackets, so you don't need to think about escaping them.

Comment: Yeah - thanks Neolisk! - I think this would be a fairly easy class to write using stuff just like that or even regular expressions, I was just wondering if anyone had already created a full class specifically for this purpose.